# Prove grade-school multiplication algorithm applied to binary numbers

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, induction

I want to prove that the basic multiplication algorithm is correct when applied to binary numbers.
I try to follow the steps described [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/6315/112500) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/52198/112500) but didn't succeed.

The basic implementation algorithm is the `multiply` function defined below, the other functions are given by completeness (this is F# but it reads as pseudo code):

```
let toBitsArray (x : int) =
    let bitArray = System.Collections.BitArray(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(x))
    let bits = Array.zeroCreate<bool> bitArray.Count
    bitArray.CopyTo(bits, 0)
    bits

(* Gives an array of bits (bool: 1 or 0) in little endian representation 
   for example 5 = 00000000000000000000000000000101 (32 bits)
   the function will give this array:
   [|true; false; true; false; false; false; false; false; false; false; 
     false; false; false; false; false; false; false; false; false;
     false; false; false; false; false; false; false; false; false;
     false; false; false; false|] 
   which represents 10100000000000000000000000000000 (32 bits) *)
let toLittleEndianBitsArray (x : int) = 
    let bits = toBitsArray x
    if System.BitConverter.IsLittleEndian
    then bits
    else Array.rev bits

let multiply (x : int) (y : int) =
    let by = toLittleEndianBitsArray y
    let rec loop (x : int64) (y : bool list) =
        if List.isEmpty y 
        then 0L
        else 
            let h = List.head y        
            let t = List.tail y
            if h
            then x + (loop (x <<< 1) t)
            else loop (x <<< 1) t

    loop (int64 x) (List.ofArray by)
```

Comment: Is there a specific step in the proofs you linked that is tripping you up?

Comment: well, I'm not being able of coming with an induction step that eases the proof, in the examples I linked there is `P(m) = x+y=m+1, m >= 2 and x, y >= 1` then it proves the recursion with `multiplication(x-1,y)` but I have to prove it with `multiplication( leftshift x, y)`... I do not see how to proceed